# Chrome Remote Desktop Keyboard Shortcut Needed

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, chrome-remote-desktop

I'm using Chrome Remote Desktop on a Windows Desktop to access an Apple iMac. I cannot figure out how to invoke the Apple Command key function from my Windows keyboard. I would think that the Windows key would work but it doesn't. Is there a way to map the Windows key to the Apple Command key? I really want to be able to invoke copy and paste from the keyboard, which are Command-C and Command-V on the iMac, so I'm stuck because I don't have a "Command" key.

Answer (score 52):

My solution to this problem is to leverage the handy "Configure Key Mapping" command provided by the latest version of Chrome Remote Desktop (v. 77.0 at the time of writing). The option is available in the sidebar as shown below.

[image]

Clicking the link opens the "Configure Key Mapping" dialog, from which you can create your own mapping. An important thing to note is that the keycodes supported by Chrome Remote Desktop are not the usual "ASCII" codes to which every developer is used to (I did this error myself the first time); rather, the codes should be taken from the "[UI Events KeyboardEvent code Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events-code/)" W3C standard. If you go through the standard you'll find the useful "List of code values for functional keys in the Alphanumeric section" table, which I also replicate below.

[image]

Concretely, let's say you want to map your local (Windows) **Ctrl** key to the remote (Mac) **Cmd** key. From the table above we see that the code for the (left) Ctrl key is "ControlLeft", while the code for the Cmd key is "MetaLeft", so from the "Configure Key Mappings" dialog:

1. click "New Mapping"
2. enter "ControlLeft" in the "from" field
3. enter "MetaLeft" in the "to" field
4. if needed, click [New Mapping] to enter more key mappings
5. the configuration should now look like in the image below. Click [Done] to close the dialog window.

[image]

At this point you should be able to use Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V etc. on your local PC to trigger the corresponding Cmd-C, Cmd-V etc. commands in the remote Mac. The solution works quite well for me and it resolves a perennial problem of how to use the Cmd button while on a Windows PC without having to rely on external apps or plugins.

Comment: This seems to resolve the issue, and more importantly, you can use the intuitive Ctrl key instead of the Windows key.

Comment: For those coming from google THIS is the best answer. Also if you're remoting from Windows 10 into macOS the one you want to map is: `AltLeft` -> `MetaLeft`. This will restore alt tab ability and make your windows 10 hotkeys work a lot more like mac hotkeys.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but I use the left Ctrl too often, so I mapped ShiftRight to MetaLeft and that seems to work just fine. Right shift is now my Command key in Chrome Remote Desktop.

Comment: I I don't know where to ask this question so ...
Is it possible to map a key combination. For example: Shift + ControlLeft + P to PrintScreen ?

Comment: yes, I also want to know how to pass 'left Alt + space' to the remote machine.

Comment: I let this bug me for far too long before googling it and finding this answer.  Thank you!

Comment: what is the keyboard shortcut to go full screen. that is why i came here to this post.

Comment: found it. select keyboard shortcut. enable. then choose `Alt` for example. i choose `Right Alt.` so `RightAlt` +`F` will toggle full screen.

Answer (score 8):

I'm on a Windows 10 machine remoting into an El Capitan Mac (yes, it's an old OS, but it's a 2009 model that can't be upgraded any higher). If the other solutions don't work for you (they didn't for me), you can try adding Mac keyboard shortcuts in Keyboard settings. I use this mac as a home server and *only* use it via Chrome Remote Desktop, so I am not worried about messing up keyboard shortcuts when using the computer's keyboard directly.

Go to `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts` and add new shortcut mappings for Copy and Paste to the `Ctrl` key.

[image: Re-mapping Copy and Paste in Settings]

Comment: This works! From `Windows 10` to `VSCode` on `Mac OSX High Sierra`

Comment: Pasting in the terminal isn't working though. Would be better to have a general solution which mapped ctrl to cmd from CRD

Comment: Wow, you are a genius! Can't believe this actually worked!

My problem was: using a windows keyboard on a mac laptop. To use the control I switch the modifiers key cmd <-> ctrl. The problem was that when I'd Chrome Remote Desktop to a Linux machine, that was double reversed back. And CRD remapping did not actually remap the MetaLeft char to ControlLeft, for whatever reason (probably bug, because the remapping from ControlLeft to MetaLeft did work). Anyways, I now have my keyboard working consistently everywhere!

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 10

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: The OP specifically mentions being on a Mac.

Comment: This does answer the question. It is the best answer here. When connecting to a Mac, Alt + Window seems to behave as Cmd on the remote Mac.

Comment: @PeterCrotty I think that is partially true. For example I was not able to save a document having shortcut cmd + S or undo an action with cmd + Z

Answer (score 5):

On an Acer C7, the right control key maps to command.  In fact, the Search key maps to command too, which is far more helpful, but available on fewer keyboards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, that's not working on my Microsoft wireless keyboard. I still haven't found a key that will map to the Apple Command key under Chrome Remote Desktop. If I connect directly to the iMac instead of using Chrome Remote Desktop the Windows key on this keyboard DOES map to the Apple Command Key. What I need is a way to specify/configure the keyboard mapping that Chrome Remote Desktop is using for this session.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it seems I can use the Windows Key to send the CMD Key straight away to the Mac machine. I have tried:

```
Windows + C: copy
Windows + V: paste
Windows + X: Cut
Windows + W: close window
Windows + Q: close application
```

All work nice!
However you can't use this:

```
Windows + Tab:  switch between applications, 
                it is already used by Windows for the same function.
```

But you can still use "holding the mouse middle wheel and moving the mouse up" to see all open applications. It is a little bit painful, but does most jobs.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - on Win10 Windows + C opens cortana while Windows + X opens the shut down menu...

Comment: Same to me (Windows 10 again)

Answer (score 3):

If things don't work - try map Meta**Right** to ControlLeft

I have windows keyboard connected to a mapbook. I had to swap the modifier keys: Command <-> Control.

The problem was that when connecting with the Chrome Remote Desktop to a Linux machine, the remapping MetaLeft to ControlLeft did not work. Turned out it's because the macbook remapped the left key to the Meta**Right** what whatever reason.

Comment: This also helped me when remoting from a MacBook to a Windows machine.

Comment: +100
Solved my issue remoting from MacOS into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

### Go Full-Screen first

In order to use all shortcut keys, you need to go full screen from the Windows PC that is accessing the Mac. This option can be found in the side menu on the right.

[image]

Then use the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key for all the <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> key shortcut keys on Mac

Comment: what is the keyboard shortcut to go full screen. that is why i came here to this post.

Comment: found it. select keyboard shortcut. enable. then choose `Alt` for example. i choose Right Alt. so RightAlt + F will toggle full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed, using chrome remote desktop, that search+another_key does the same as CMD+another_key while remote-connected to my mac-book pro over home WiFi. I also noted that if I want to enter two search+another_key presses sequentially, I must release and repress the search key after each instance

Answer (score 0):

You can map keybindings, just not that im on a mac remoting to a windows PC (with a windows keyboard) and I noticed that MetaRight is the windows key (as oppose to Meta left).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use e.g. `WIN-key + C` to represent `Cmd + C` on mac, other than "Configure key mappings" (`WIN-key` seems mean `Cmd` on mac by default?), you need to go to full-screen checkbox by the right-side's blue-sliding bar (F11 doesn't work for me).

Only in that full-screen mode, `WIN-key + something` is not occupied by the Windows OS.